# search button + gridview

Tags: c#

I have a gridview which shows all the information of the data table. I have a textbox and a button. If I want to search some particular files in the gridview, I need to enter the filename in textbox and hit search button. I'm taking care of this with the code

```
// don't copy and paste this; it is vulnerable to sql injection attacks
SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = 
    "select * from Table1 where FileName like '%" + TextBox1.Text + "%'"  ;
SqlDataSource1.DataBind();
```

I want to display the message like "file not found" if there are no search results. How can I do that?

Comment: This code is very unsafe, you are allowing your users to execute SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the emptydatatext property. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.emptydatatext(v=VS.90).aspx

```
<asp:GridView EmptyDataText="File Not Found" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You should get the **DataTable** from the DataSource of the GridView and use the **Select** method of the DataTable which returns an array of **DataRows** object, if that returned array is null or its count is zero, you can popup a 'file not found' message.

MSDN Reference: [DataTable.Select Method (String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/det4aw50.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you

```
if (((DataTable)SqlDataSource1).rows.count < 1)
{
       //file not found
}
```